# How to save data in a class object ,sent as json object from jsp page to controller in spring using jackson?

Tags: jquery, json, spring, jsp

I am trying to send a json object from a jsp page using jquery ajax to a controller in spring framework. I want to fetch the jsonobject elements and store it in a class object using jackson.
Here is what I have tried:
jsp page:

```
function callme(){
var jsonDataObject = new Object();
   jsonDataObject.name = "abc";
   jsonDataObject.pwd = "123";
   var jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonDataObject);
$.ajax({
type:"get",
url:"/test",
async:   false,
data:{jsonData:jsonData},
dataType:"json",
success:function(data){
}
```

controller:

```
 @RequestMapping (value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
    public  String test(@RequestBody User obj)
    {
      System.out.println("I am in user");
        ResponseVO respVo = new ResponseVO();

        System.out.println("User name is:"+obj.getName());
        System.out.println("User password is:"+obj.getPwd());

}
```

What i got is 415  unsupported media type error.
please help.

Comment: Do you have a (de)serializer (I keep forgetting which turns the JSON into a Java object and vice versa) for User? Also, you are wrapping the JSON into another object, so if you do not have a (de)serializer for User, Jackson is probably trying to do (essentially) `user.setName = jsonData.name` but that would fail, since the value `abc` is under `jsonData.jsonData.name`

Comment: @Vld: for using jackson, i have only added the required jars. basically, i want to directly copy the data received from jsp to an object of my class.what to do? i don't want to copy element by element.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Documentation](http://spring.io/blog/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/) says that if you have this dependency in your pom.xml and the tag `<mvc:annotation-driven>` in your spring context, Spring MVC automatically registers a JSON converter for your REST template

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope you have a REST template defined in your application.

Comment: where do i have to place these beans --in mvcdispatcher.xml or web.xml?

Comment: Same place you have defined your REST template. Can you also check if <mvc:annotation-driven/> is present in your dispatcher servlet. It auto registers this converter.

Comment: basically, i want to directly copy the data received from jsp to an object of my class.what to do? i don't want to copy element by element, as we do with key-value pair.

Comment: Basically what you are doing here is mapping a JSON string {"name":"abc","pwd":"123"} to an Object of type User. Is your User a class which has these fields name, pwd with appropriate setters/getter? If yes, next thing you need to do is register a JSON converter with your REST template. I am editing my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes we do have that POJO . Now , how to register JSON convertor.

Comment: :Yes we do have that POJO . Now , how to register JSON convertor.

Comment: I have added the dependency for jackson-mapper,core,jaxrs,xs. Also i got this error now:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.

Comment: The spring web dependency seems to be missing. Please make sure all spring related dependencies are in place.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the type of data used by the controller :

```
 @RequestMapping (value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET,consumes = "application/json)
  @ResponseBody
    public  String test(@RequestBody User obj)
    {
      System.out.println("I am in user");
        ResponseVO respVo = new ResponseVO();

        System.out.println("User name is:"+obj.getName());
        System.out.println("User password is:"+obj.getPwd());

}
```

Comment: it gives error:The attribute consumes is undefined for the annotation type RequestMapping

Comment: Which is your Spring version ? Could you post your pom file please ?

Comment: <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>